# WebStore "This app can be used even when there is no connection to the Internet."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store

Some apps in Chrome WebStore have a little bolt icon that when you hover over them it says: "This app can be used even when there is no connection to the Internet."

[image]

I have an extension that doesn't need internet connectivity at all, but it is not marked with that bolt. I was wondering what are the conditions to be detected as an offline app in WebStore?

Comment: Are you sure they never asked you whether or not your app would work?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks. Would you consider writing this as an answer?

Comment: @AlexStack So, they ask you as you're setting up your app in the store?

Comment: Yes it's a setting in the manifest. It is written clearly. You can get your score for a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is adding this line to your **manifest.json** file

```
"offline_enabled":true,
```